# Realurl config combination of domain an get-parameter for language

Tags: php, typo3, realurl, multiple-languages

Hidiho,

i got a TYPO3-Site with many translations for each langauge.

The Realurl-config for the translations are working fine, if a have a certain domain. For example domainname.com, domainname.de, domainname.es and  so on.

Now i want to add a new translation (Portuguese), but i don't have a domain for it. I want to use the url domainname.com/pt for the new translation.

Does RealUrl supports this different way of use?

Previews in Backend are not working fine.
The langauge-Menu contains an the correct Link, but when opening it, i get the standard-langauge (en).

In TS:

```
configname {
    baseURL = https://www.domainname.com
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = en
    locale_all = en_EN
    htmlTag_langKey = en
}

[globalVar = GP:L = 0]
configname {
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = en
    locale_all = en_EN
    htmlTag_langKey = en
}
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
configname {
    sys_language_uid = 1
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE
    htmlTag_langKey = de
    baseURL = https://www.domainname.de
}
[global]

....

#new config for portuguese
[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
    configname {
        sys_language_uid = 3
        language = pt
        locale_all = pt_PT
        htmlTag_langKey = pt
    }
[global]
```

perhaps i don't know to config realurl_conf.php correctly for this purpose.

Here it comes:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
'preVars' => array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array(
            'pt' => '3',
        ),
        'valueDefault' => '',
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
    ),
),
....
);

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS'] = array(
'encode' => array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
        'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domainname.com',
    ),
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '0',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
        'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domainname.com'
    ),
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '1',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
        'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domainname.de'
    ),

    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '2',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
        'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domainname.es'
    ),

    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '4',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
        'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domainname.cn'
    ),

    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '6',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
        'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.domainname.com'
    ),

),

'decode' => array(
    'www.domainname.com' => array(
        'GETvars' => array(
            'L' => '0',
        ),
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT',
    ),

    'www.domainname.de' => array(
        'GETvars' => array(
            'L' => '1',
        ),
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT'
    ),

    'www.domainname.es' => array(
        'GETvars' => array(
            'L' => '2',
        ),
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT'
    ),

    'www.domainname.cn' => array(
        'GETvars' => array(
            'L' => '4',
        ),
        'useConfiguration' => '_DEFAULT'
    ),
   ),
);
```

Any suggestions how to say realurl that its the langauge 3 it has to use?

Comment: Shouldn't it read "config" instead of "configname" in your ts-setup?

Comment: temp hint: you didn't anymize your realurl properly, btw ;)

Comment: to look at this in detail, you might want to contact me in slack or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your answers.

I found a solution. It's all abput the encode/decode blocks and preVars. In Addtion i hooked me into UrlDecoder (function setRequestVariables(){...}) ecspacially for my purpose (dirty fix).
One Configuration is enough to get real_url work for mixing up multi-domain and language-parameters.

realurl_conf.php

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
    'init' => array(
        'enableCHashCache' => true,
        'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
        'enableUrlDecodeCache' => true,
        'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    'preVars' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'en' => '0',
                'de' => '1',
                'es' => '2',
                'pt' => '3',
                'cn' => '4',
                'it' => '5',
                'us' => '6',
                'fr' => '7',
            ),
            'valueDefault' => 'en',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

Now the Endcode/Decode Block:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['example.org'] = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS'] = array(
    'encode' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '0',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.org'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '1',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.de'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '2',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.es'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '3',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.org/pt'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '4',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.cn'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '6',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.org/us'
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'value' => '7',
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org',
            'urlPrepend' => 'https://www.example.org/fr'
        )
    ),

    'decode' => array(
        'example.com' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '0',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        ),
        'example.de' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '1',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        ),
        'example.es' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '2',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        ),
        'example.pt' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '3',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        ),
        'example.cn' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '4',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        ),
        'example.us' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '6',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        ),
        'example.fr' => array(
            'GETvars' => array(
                'L' => '7',
            ),
            'useConfiguration' => 'example.org'
        )
    )
);
```

RealurlUrlDecoder.php

```
use DmitryDulepov\Realurl\Cache\UrlCacheEntry;
class RealurlUrlDecoder extends \DmitryDulepov\Realurl\Decoder\UrlDecoder {


    /**
     * Sets variables after the decoding.
     *
     * @param UrlCacheEntry $cacheEntry
     */
    public function setRequestVariables(UrlCacheEntry $cacheEntry) {

        $languageWithoutDomain = array(
            3 => '/pt/',
            6 => '/us/',
            7 => '/fr/',
        );

        if (in_array(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4), $languageWithoutDomain)) {
            foreach ($languageWithoutDomain as $key => $value) {
                 if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 4) == $value){
                    $requestVariables = $cacheEntry->getRequestVariables();
                    if(isset($requestVariables['L'])){
                        $requestVariables['L'] = $key;
                        $cacheEntry->setRequestVariables($requestVariables);
                    } 
                }
             }
         }

        parent::setRequestVariables($cacheEntry);

    }
}
```

Comment: Clearing the complete real_url cache after editing the Configuration is important, because the translated site-Title can be the same

Answer (score 0):

Multilanguange/Multidomain config is not trivial to achieve...
I never mixed the different modes, though.

The biggest problem I see at first glance
is that alll your domain config use the same [_default] configuration -
I always create dedicated arrays for each domains like this:

```
// [_default] stuff

$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['whatever.de']  = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['whatever.de']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = 1;
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['whatever.com']  = $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['whatever.com']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = 1;

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS']['encode'] = array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '0',
        'useConfiguration' => 'whatever.de',
        'urlPrepend' => 'http://whatever.de',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
    ),
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'value' => '1',
        'useConfiguration' => 'whatever.com',
        'urlPrepend' => 'http://whatever.com',
        'ifDifferentToCurrent' => true,
    ),
// ...
);

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DOMAINS']['decode'] = array(
    'whatever.de' => array(
        'GETvars' => array(
            'L' => '0',
        ),
        'useConfiguration' => 'whatever.de'
    ),
    'whatever.com' => array(
        'GETvars' => array(
            'L' => '1',
        ),
        'useConfiguration' => 'whatever.com'
    ),
// ...
);
```

But the cleanest  solution would definitely be to aquire the necessary .pt domain, imho.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to add a new translation (Portuguese), but i don't have a domain for it. I want to use the url domainname.com/pt for the new translation.
>
> Does RealUrl supports this different way of use?

No, it does not. It either domains, or language segments.